# Do I've to set variable to null always in AS3 OOP?

Tags: oop, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I've a question about variables in AS3 OOP. Do I have to set them to null or I it's not needed when I define them in beginning of the class? I just noticed someone doing so so I wasn't sure is it right or no.

```
private var _mcComponentHolder:MovieClip = null;
private var _mcComponentHolder:MovieClip;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note - "I have" shouldn't be contracted to "I've" if you're asking "Do I have to...".  Likewise e.g. "I have to go out" shouldn't be written as "I've to go out", although "I'm to go out" is probably OK.  </Pedantry>

Comment: Thank you for correcting me - English is not my first language.

Comment: My pleasure - English is full of such oddities!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think either of those is fine. I've never bothered declaring it as null.

Comment: An object will always be `null` before instantiation.

Comment: Thanks nikc, I will removed the null declaration then. :)